# How to calculate mersenne numbers in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

***Note:*** this Q&A is not about the [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), but [Mersenne numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

---

I want to compute, at compile time, an array of size N containing Mersenne primes (2<sup>*n*</sup> − 1) for *n* in [0, N - 1].

```
template <std::uint8_t N>
static constexpr std::array<std::uint16_t, N> mersenne_numbers()
{

    // Compute Mersenne numbers for N, N-1 ... 1 and return the array
    return { 1, 2, 3 };
};

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<std::uint16_t, 5> arr = mersenne_numbers<5>();
}
```

How can I implement that ?

Comment: @lordjohncena Good question.

Comment: The title of the  question  is misleading, it should  be  *how to cacuclate mesenne numbers in compile time*.

Comment: @lordjohncena,  for  performance, I would imagine?

Comment: From http://www.elbeno.com/blog/?p=1284 "only a madman would try to implement a Mersenne Twister in C++11 constexpr-land."

Comment: There is a point where the compile time computation is so complex that you are better off writing a program that dumps whatever you need to a data file; Or a header file if you need that to be compile time constant.

Comment: @lordjohncena,  I won't  pretend that I know what Mersenne number is, but from the question it seems like it is something you can calculate for a natural number - and I understand you might want to have an array of those already precalculated for you to use at runtime.

Comment: Guys... this is about [Mersenne numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), not the Mersenne twister.

Comment: @Quentin Ah..ok. so it seems all that is needed is a constexpr version of `std::pow(2, n) - 1`

Comment: SergeyA A Mersenne [prime] number is a prime number which is equal to  `2^n - 1` for some natural n. (and `^` means "power of", not Xor)

Comment: @Arunm: not all numbers of that form are primes, you need to filter them

Comment: @Dani: *"numbers of the form Mn = 2^n − 1 without the primality requirement are called Mersenne numbers. "*. You confound with Mersenne **primes**.

Comment: @OP: I've left the "primes" when editing, could you confirm whether you're looking for Mersenne primes or merely Mersenne numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to compute an array of (2^n - 1) at compile time, you may do

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::array<std::uint16_t, sizeof...(Is)>
mersenne_numbers(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{ ((1u << Is) - 1u)... }};
}

template <std::uint8_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::uint16_t, N>
mersenne_numbers()
{
    return mersenne_numbers(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pdRcjO)

implementation of `index_sequence` stuff can be done in c++11, and found easily on SO.

Or even in c++14

```
template <std::uint8_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::uint16_t, N> mersenne_numbers()
{
    std::array<std::uint16_t, N> res{};
    for (uint i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
        res [i] = (1u << i) - 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/XxU3Ag)

Comment: I agree that this works, but I'm curious...am I wrong if I say that we don't need template meta-programming to compute this at compile-time? Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution

Comment: @lordjohncena: `constexpr` functions are limited in c++11, but c++14 allows to write it in a natural way. see edit.

Comment: Thanks I'd double upvote if I could!

Answer (score 0):

Using C++14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int cpow2(int n) {
  return n == 0 ? 1 : 2 * cpow2(n-1);
}

template <size_t... Seq>
static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Seq)> mersenne_numbers(std::index_sequence<Seq...> isq)
{
  return {(cpow2(Seq)-1)...};
}


int main() {
  static_assert (cpow2(4) == 16, "");
  auto arr = mersenne_numbers(std::make_index_sequence<5>());
  for (auto e : arr) std::cout << e << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Between, @Jarod42 implementation is better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about marsenne numbers, but you always could modify this example 
(computes `x^x`):

```
template <std::uint8_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::uint64_t, N> power_one
    (std::array<std::uint64_t, N> arr,
     const uint8_t num)
{
    arr[num] = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::pow(num, num));
    return arr;
}

template <std::uint8_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::uint64_t, N> self_powered
(std::array<std::uint64_t, N> arr = std::array<std::uint64_t, N>{0},
     const uint8_t step = 0)
{
    return step>=N? arr : self_powered(power_one(arr, step), step + 1);
}

s32 main()
{
    auto arr = self_powered<10>();
    for(auto& x : arr)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fail with `constexpr` [Demo](https://ideone.com/j6CFZ6), even if without it computes `x^x` [Demo](https://ideone.com/VPHYTO)

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, I have set c++14 as default in my IDE, so I was my oversight. About what it computes, it was supposed to compute `x^x`, because it was only an example how to implement such mechanism :)

Comment: `std::pow` is not `constexpr`.